# Reserved keyword in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

in C# you'd put a `@` in front of a reserved keyword.

Is there any equivalent in vb .net?

Comment: but then, don't be using reserved keywords as names....

Comment: It's still necessary to do this sometimes, like when using the `Delegate` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the keyword in `[]`:

```
Class [As]
End Class

Dim [Dim] As [As]
```

Comment: @Mitch sometimes you have to, e.g. when using Delegate class as Timiz0r said

Comment: sure. I meant when avoidable.